# Errors in simple template code

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

```
template <class T>
struct ABC
{
      typedef typename T* pT;     
};

int main(){}
```

The above piece of code gives errors

`expected nested-name-specifier before 'T'`
`expected ';' before '*' token`

What is wrong with the code sample?

Comment: This would be of use : http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~driscoll/typename.html

Answer (score 9):

The keyword `typename` is forbidden on unqualified names (those not preceded by `::`), even if they are dependent.

C++03 [Section `14.6/5`] says

> The keyword **typename shall be applied only to qualified names**, but those names need not be dependent.

`pt` is dependent on T but that doesn't matter (in this context).

Remove `typename` to make your code compile.